# Detect Flash Player full screen mode and inject CSS on top of it using Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, flash

I'm looking for a way to detect the switch to a full flash video using an injected content script running in a Chrome Extension. Would anyone happen to know how this could be possible ? Once that's done, I would also love to be able to somehow display CSS or any other kind of stylized data on top of that now full screen Flash window. Basically, a "Hello World!" version of this extension would just display a message on top of a video (from Youtube or any other website using the flash player) after it switched to full screen. If you know more about being able to do it, please share your experience, as I just have no real idea of what's going on with Flash's interaction with the browser. Tell me if you need any more details. Thanks for your time !

Comment: You can easily overlap html content over embed objects like flash, however when flash goes full screen you will have no possible way of doing so and everything on the screen will be flash content only.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. Is there no way, even if it means using windows API calls, a certain trick or something entirely different than Chrome to achieve the same effect ? I just want to draw things over a full screen flash window, it doesn't matter that much how I achieve it (though a Chrome based solution would suit me best)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be to use webkit fullscreen

```
document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
```

And set the flash width/height properties to 100% and probably scale to noScale
That sounds a bit hackish tho, not too sure what you're trying to achieve.